# Fuse on Primary Side of Transformer keeps blowing

Tags: transformer, fuses

I have a HVAC which is having a 24V 40VAC transformer. I might have shorted the output of the transformer while working on the wires.

I noticed that the fuses on the input side of transformer blew off and I replaced them with time delay 2A fuses. I unloaded the output of transformer (open circuit) to test if transformer is providing the right volts. Here the fuses blew off again.

Is it because the transformer is bad or I am using wrong fuses here ?

Transformer: Input: 240V 
Output: 24V 40VAC

Comment: *I might have sorted the output* Do you mean s**h**orted? *I unloaded the o/p of transformer* what does o/p mean? If you want help, at least make your question clear and don't use abbreviations. Did you replace the fuse with a new fuse having the **same ratings**?

Comment: It had mda 2A fuse which i replaced with mdl 2a fuse. The both are slow blow fuse but not sure if that's what is causing it.

Comment: Does the transformer name plate read 'Primary 240V~ 50Hz, Secondary 24V - 40VA'? Does it have only 2 windings and have you inadvertently applied 240V on the secondary side?

Comment: The transformer take either 208V or 240V and the inputs are labeled. The o/p is 24V 40VA. I  provided input to the 240V

Comment: If disrupting the current in a transformer you will generate voltage spikes. U=L*dI/dt. Så large/fast current change dI in short time dt will give a large voltage spike. L is the inductance of the windings. This could have damaged the isolation in your transformer and led to a short circuit. This you can measure with an ohm meter provided you know what value is should be!

Answer (score 1):

If the input side of the X-former is blowing fuses with no-load on the output, you killed your transformer when you shorted it before.   In a no-load situations, using a previously known good transformer, the fuses (even if not the right size) should not be blowing.

Comment: is there a possibility of inrush current with no load on secondary causes fuses to blew quickly? trying to understand how i can properly test the transformer to make sure its not bad.

Comment: No.    An open secondary will result in nearly zero inrush current.     Re: testing - You're already testing it with fuses    ;)      No point in me typing out "how to test a transformer", when you can google it...     i.e. https://www.hunker.com/13414369/how-to-test-a-24-volt-transformer

Comment: Actually that was a lame link.  Sorry.   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D0OQvuux6CE   is a little better.   Unfortunately, you can't always prove a transformer is good with just an ohmmeter, but you can sometimes prove it's bad.